# Sort subgroups of lines with command-line tools

Tags: bash, command-line

I've been trying to find a way of sorting this with standard commandline tools, bash, awk, sort, whatever but can't find a way apart from using perl or similar.

Any hint?

**Input data**

```
header1
3
2
5
1

header2
5
1
3
.....
.....
```

**Output data**

```
header1
1
2
3
5

header2
1
....
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumes sections are separated by blank lines and the header doesn't necessarily contain the string "header". Leaves the sections in the original order so the sort is stable. Reads from stdin, displays on stdout.

```
#!/bin/bash

function read_section() {
    while read LINE && [ "$LINE" ]; do echo "$LINE"; done
}

function sort_section() {
    read HEADER && (echo "$HEADER"; sort; echo)
}

while read_section | sort_section; do :; done
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
cat test.txt | while (while read LINE && [ "$LINE" ]; do echo "$LINE"; done) | (read HEADER && (echo "$HEADER"; sort; echo)); do :; done
```

Comment: Damn, I knew somebody'd throw me a "Useless Use of Cat Award" for that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mark@ubuntu:~$ cat /tmp/test.txt
header1
3
2
5
1

header2
5
1
3
mark@ubuntu:~$ cat /tmp/test.txt | awk '/header/ {colname=$1; next} {print colname, "," , $0}'  | sort | awk '{if ($1 != header) {header = $1; print header} print $3}'
header1

1
2
3
5
header2
1
3
5
```

To get rid of the blank lines, I guess you can add a "| grep -v '^$'" at the end...

Answer (score 0):

Use AWK to prefix the `header` to each number line.
`sort` the resulting file.
remove the prefix to return the file to original format.

Comment: hmm, can you elaborate that? note that those headers are not necessarily ordered, the sort should be stable.

Comment: @Arkaitz, `Mark` has given an example of what I was saying. +1 to him for working that out (and maybe -1 to you for not trying?, ok, i am kidding there).

Answer (score 0):

with GNU awk, you can use its internal sort functions.

```
awk 'BEGIN{ RS=""}
{
    print $1
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
        a[i]=$i
    }
    b=asort(a,d)
    for(i=1;i<=b;i++){    
        print d[i]
    }
    delete d
    delete a    
} ' file
```

output

```
# more file
header1
3
2
5
1

header2
5
1
3
# ./test.sh
header1
1
2
3
5
header2
1
3
5
```